# How to get multiple PDF files from asset folder

Tags: android, pdf

How to get multiple pdf files from the asset folder and how to pass these pdf file one fragment to another fragment in android studio

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
      viewHolder.tv.setText(textarray[i]);  
      viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(imagearray[i]);
      File pdffile = new File( "res/raw/kutta.pdf" );
      Uri path = Uri.fromFile( pdffile );
}
```

[first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSvqu.jpg)

[second view onclick of options from list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSd6z.jpg)

Comment: Please ask question with more information.

Comment: Please provide more information about the code which you have shared.